# How to display JSON array using ng-repeat in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

This should be simple but I'm not able to solve this and have no idea where I am going wrong. I have an angular module that is supposed to repeat the data that is a JSON array; My controller and module looks like the one below

```
 (function() {

var timeslots = data;

var app =   angular.module('TimeSlot', []);

app.controller("TimeSlotController", function(timeslots) {

    this.timeslots = JSON.parse(timeslots);

});

})();


 <div ng-app="TimeSlot">
                <div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="TimeSlotController as slot" ng-repeat="item in slot.timeslots" >
                     <div class="col-md-4 timeblock">
                        <h3 class="event-type-name">{{ item.time }} Hour Appointment</h3>
                        <div class="description mts">{{ item.description}}</div>
                        <div class="cost"><i class="fa fa-euro"></i>{{ item.cost }}</div>
                     </div>
                </div>

             </div> 

        </div>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var data = {{{ timeslot }}}     
        </script>
        <script src="/js/timeslot.js"></script>
```

This is the data that I am trying to parse,

```
vardata=[
{
    "time": 1,
    "description": "Here lies 1",
    "cost": "10"
},
{
    "time": 2,
    "description": "Here lies 2",
    "cost": "20"
},
{
    "time": 3,
    "description": "Here lies 3",
    "cost": "10"
}
```

]

Any help will be appreciated, I have taken a look at other posts and I have not been able to figure it out, so sorry if it is a duplicate post.

Comment: You're missing a key portion of code – where is slot.timeslots declared?

Comment: why are controllers ng-repeated?

Comment: In Angular you normally use `$scope` to hold your data and inject it in your Controllers and such.

Comment: @PM77-1 , actually in 1.3 $scope is not required anymore and the this.timeslots is valid way of assigning

Comment: Thanks, I got this from the CodeSchool tutorial but now I have another problem, the fields inside {{}} are not displaying at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is `data` global? you can not to inject simple variables to your controller.
Try to delete argument from controller function.
Also why you parse already parsed data?

Just pust your data to `$scope`:

```
app.controller("TimeSlotController", function($scope) {

    $scope.timeslots = timeslots;

});
```

And use it inside your controllers view:

```
<div ng-controller="TimeSlotController">
 <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="item in timeslots">
    {{item}}
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: data is global,kind of new to the whole angular way of doing things still learning, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you repeat the controller, then the variable timeslots is not available on the same line.
Try your HTML like so:

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="TimeSlotController as slot"  >
    <div class="col-md-4 timeblock" ng-repeat="item in slot.timeslots">
        <h3 class="event-type-name">{{ item.time }} Hour Appointment</h3>
        <div class="description mts">{{ item.description}}</div>
            <div class="cost"><i class="fa fa-euro"></i>{{ item.cost }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, my mistake was with the ng-repeat thing; thanks a lot you saved me a lot of time

Comment: It is angular via backdoor using. Bad things happened if you are put your data without scope :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $scope, with which angular bind data from controller to views and vicevers.

```
app.controller('TimeSlotController', function ($scope){
    $scope.timeslots =  JSON.parse(timeslots);
});
```

So, in your view you just spell it like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in timeslots">
```

ps: sqs my english

Comment: Where you define `timeslots` provider?